Difficulty converting SNOMED codes to ICD-10 in R
I am working on a project where I need to compute comorbidity scores. However, the data I am working with uses SNOMED codes instead of ICD codes. I am aware of the comorbidity package in R, which is excellent but it seems to support only ICD-9 and ICD-10 codes.
I came across the Rdiagnosislist package, which seems promising for converting SNOMED codes to ICD-10. However, when attempting to use the package's functionality for this purpose, I encountered an error:
Converting 1 concept(s) to a codelist
Error in get(SNOMEDname, envir = globalenv()) : object 'SNOMED' not found

It seems that the Rdiagnosislist package is unable to recognize the SNOMED concept. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or knows how to resolve it? I would appreciate any insights or alternative approaches for converting SNOMED codes to ICD-10 in R.
install.packages("Rdiagnosislist")
library(Rdiagnosislist)


# Assume '713705003' is your SNOMED concept id
snomed_concept_id <- '713705003'
getMaps(SNOMEDcodelist(SNOMEDconcept(snomed_concept_id)), to = c('icd10'))


did you follow the instructions here? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rdiagnosislist/vignettes/SNOMEDcodelists.html
it doesnt look like you loaded a SNOMED object/dictionary
"# Import using the loadSNOMED function
SNOMED <- loadSNOMED(tempdir(), active_only = FALSE)
Make sure the SNOMED environment is available and contains the SNOMED dictionary
SNOMEDconcept('Heart failure', SNOMED = SNOMED)"
and so on

Oh, interesting! I had assumed that only the SNOMED code was necessary. Isn't the code meant to be generic? What's the rationale behind obscuring it and making access difficult?
